# What's wrong with Geospatial queries using Polygons and Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, mongoose

I'm doing a geospatial query using a `$polygon` search. My query is:

```
{
    'location_latLong': {
        '$within': {
            '$polygon': {
                point1: {
                    lon: '-74.2621',
                    lat: '40.5788'
                },
                point2: {
                    lon: '-74.2621',
                    lat: '40.8494'
                },
                point3: {
                    lon: '-73.7499',
                    lat: '40.8494'
                },
                point4: {
                    lon: '-73.7499',
                    lat: '40.5788'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my collection, I have a document that CLEARLY lies within the polygon:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4e95c285cb8a0efc2b00001a"),
    "addedOn": Date(1318437509839),
    "checkinDate": Date(1318392000000),
    "checkinTime": Date(1318437476000),
    "location_city": "New York",
    "location_country": "United States",
    "location_latLong": {
        "xLon": -74.007124,
        "yLat": 40.71455
    },
    "location_source": "personprofile",
    "location_state": "New York",
    "location_zip": ""
}
```

and I have a `2d` index on `location_latLong`. I know that MongoDB ignores key names (supposedly), so that shouldn't matter. So why does this return 0 results?

**EDIT**
I just ran an `explain` as recommended in the comments and I get:

```
{
    "cursor" : "GeoBrowse-polygon",
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "location_latLong" : [
            [
                [
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    0.000021457672119140625,
                    0.000021457672119140625
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    -0.000021457672119140625,
                    -0.000021457672119140625
                ],
                [
                    0,
                    0
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    -0.000021457672119140625,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    0,
                    0.000021457672119140625
                ]
            ],
            [
                [
                    0,
                    -0.000021457672119140625
                ],
                [
                    0.000021457672119140625,
                    0
                ]
            ]
        ]
    },
    "keysChecked" : NumberLong(8),
    "lookedAt" : NumberLong(4),
    "matchesPerfd" : NumberLong(0),
    "objectsLoaded" : NumberLong(0),
    "pointsLoaded" : NumberLong(0)
}
```

Comment: this query looks good, i dont know the exact problem.. Did you get a error msg? did you specify the min/max bounds in the index..

Comment: I did not specify min / max bounds in the index as it should be -180.. 180 by default, no?

Comment: Can you remove mongoose from the equation and run this from the shell with a `.explain()`? It may clarify what's happening

Comment: @GatesVP I added an `explain` as you had suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was passing Strings and I should have been passing floats.

Thanks for your time =)